# Size of file stored on the Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have following model

```
class MediaFile(Media):
    s3_file = GenericFileField(tag="s3-tag", null=True, blank=True, max_length=300)
```

How can I get size of file stored on s3?

I tried this, but it's not work.

```
    def file_size(self):
        try:
            prefix = get_file_key(self.s3_file)
            s3 = boto3.resource("s3")
            bucket = s3.Bucket()
            return bucket.Object(prefix).content_length
        except:
            pass
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access an existing Bucket using boto3, you need to supply the bucket name, for example:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource("s3")
bucket = s3.Bucket('mybucket')
length = bucket.Object('cats/persian.jpg').content_length
```

Alternatively:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource("s3")
length = s3.Object('mybucket', 'cats/persian.jpg').content_length
```

FYI the value passed to `Bucket.Object()` is a key (like `cats/persian.jpg`), not a prefix (like `cats/`).

Comment: Thnx. How can get key of file for s3?

Comment: You don't 'get' the key for the S3 object. You know the key in advance. It's how you decide which object you're going to access. Just like a file on your local file system, you can list the available objects, if needed, and choose one.